# How to install mysql server on SUSE 10.3

Tags: mysql, linux, sles

Here is problem I have. So I download mysql 5.5.13 on the web site, but when I `rpm` the packages, it required me to update glibc.

```
Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.13-1.sles11.i586
```

I am reluctant to do it, since I might break stuffs (system calls, script and other things). For some reason, my SUSE does not have `yast2` either. (This is the company server not my personal server). So my guess would be to downgrade the mysql server rpm package to some thing that compatible with SUSE 10.3 without the need to upgrade `glibc`.

**1.Does anyone know what version of mysql server that compatible with SUSE 10.3 out of the box?**

**2.I am using SUSE Enterprise Edition 10.3, what is the likelihood that when i update glibc, something will break. I have lot of bash script running, and I am scare if I update glibc, there is chance that my bash script will not work anymore.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that no-one else has said anything, I'll make an educated guess.

Suse 10.3's active life - as head of the heap of Suse releases - was 2007-10-04 to 2008-06-19, The first MySQL version to be released within that timeframe was 5.0.51, and the closest release to the end of that span was 5.0.67.  I'd start with 5.0.67 and work down if you encounter any problems.

Comment: tyvm, I try 5.0.92 and it works. Since I am using SUSE Enterprise Edition, do you think if I upgrade glibc, will there be a chance that some of my script will not work anymore?

Comment: I am sure I am missing something here, but why not just install using YaST? I know when I had my very limited amount of time using CentOS, everything I needed was in the YUM repos. I am sure the same thing applies to SUSE.